# How to remove margins from icons in BottomNavigationView on Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, material-ui

I'm trying to remove the margins from the icons in a BottomNavigationView on Android. I've already managed to remove the text using app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled", but I can't seem to get rid of the default margins that the icons have.

Here is my XML layout:

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here is my menu file:

```xml
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/reproductive"
        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_calendar_month_24"
        android:title="Dashboard"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/dashboard"
        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_info_24"
        android:title="Reprodução"/>
</menu>
```

Approaches Tried:

1. I attempted to set android:layout_margin="0dp" in the XML of the BottomNavigationView, but the margins are still present.
2. I tried using custom styles for the BottomNavigationView, setting android:layout_margin in the style, but it didn't work either.
3. I tested android:padding="0dp" and android:layout_margin="0dp" in the XML of the BottomNavigationView, but the margins still haven't been removed.

I hope these additional details help in finding a solution. If anyone has a solution or additional suggestions, please share.

What I have
[image: example1]

Whai I want
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the source for BottomNavigationView, and there are a few parameters which are customisable.
For the problem, I think **android:minHeight = 40dp** (or some other lesser value less than default 56dp) will reduce the height of the bottom navigation view, and framework accordingly decreases the padding as well.
Let me know if this fixes the issue.

Comment: Yes, this works to reduce the size up to a certain point, but it seems to me that the margin is still there, however, it helped a lot. Thank you very much.